# Import files AppendTo and ToExpression

Tags: list-manipulation, import, files-and-directories

I have a list of files all indexed as
`filename1,filename2,filename3,...` up to 50, all in the same directory, and I wanted an `AppendTo` them to a list and `ToExpression` in index order `1,2,...,50`.

Does anyone know of a good method to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can obtain a list of filenames, e.g., by `list = FileNames[FileNameJoin[dir, "filename*"]]` where `dir` is a string specifying the directory. Afterwards you can `Map` anything over that list, for example, `Import`...

Comment: Thanks. will it do so indexed numerically? the order it is stored is crucial

Comment: Or will it do something like store `filename10,11,12,...,19,1,20,21,...,29,2`? This is the index order if you consider `FileNames` and I fear therefore it will not order my index correctly

Comment: The order is the typical lexicographical order of strings. So, yes, that may happen. That's why one should enumerate file names with leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik How could this be avoided therefore?

Comment: `Table["filename" <> IntegerString[i], {i, 1, 50}]`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I am not sure what is the input and expected output here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may generate the list of files with

```
Table[FileNameJoin[{dir,"filename" <> IntegerString[i]}], {i, 1, 50}]
```

where `dir` is a string containing the path to said directory.

Comment: So I tried `Do[AppendTo[
  ToExpression[Import["filename" <> IntegerString[i], "List"]], 
  completelist], {i, 1, 50}]` but to no avail

Comment: You have reverse the syntax of `AppendTo` Try `completelist = {}; Do[
 AppendTo[completelist, 
 ToExpression[Import["filename" <> IntegerString[i], "List"]]], {i, 1, 50}]` or something similar...

Comment: Oh my goodness of course, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.